# What is the smallest n-gon such that there can be an interior point further from all boundary points than the points are from each of their neighbors?

Tags: geometry

This is a "sequel" question to [What is the maximum n-gon such that there can't be an interior point further from all boundary points than the boundary points are from each other?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390580/what-is-the-maximum-n-gon-such-that-there-cant-be-an-interior-point-further-fro/2390616#2390616)

In the previous question I asked:

> Given a polygon with n vertices, how small can n be before it is impossible to have an interior point p such that the distance from any vertex b to p is greater than the distance from b to its nearest adjacent vertex, b'?
>
> For example, for any triangle, it seems that an interior point will be closer to at least one vertex than that vertex is to its nearest neighbor.
>
> From my own inspection, it seems like the answer might be 6 - a regular hexagon is the first shape for which a point at the center is the same distance from each vertex as the vertices are from their nearest neighbors.
>
> However, I can't figure out how to formulate a rule, or apply the intuition from the regular hexagon to irregular shapes.
>
> For my use case, it would be useful to know "below n vertices, there is no way to have such an interior point."

My updated question is: how small can $n$ be before it is impossible to have a point $p$ such that the distance from any vertex $b$ to $p$ is greater than the distance from $b$ to **either of its adjacent vertices**, $b'$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be a pair of consecutive vertices and $P$ be the point in question.  If $PA$ and $PB$ are both longer than $AB$, then angle $P$ in triangle $ABP$ has to measure less than $60°$.  To make up a full revolution there have to be seven or more different angles of this type at $P$, each opposite a different side of the polygon.

So there are no candidates with fewer than seven sides.  But the center of a regular heptagon is farther from the vertices than the length of any side making seven sides a *sharp* lower bound.

Comment: This is a really good example, thank you. I had to look up the meaning, so I'll note here: "sharp lower bound" means that 7 sides is included in the set of solutions for which this is possible.

Comment: Also, for posterity: note that the above applies to regular polygons, but it does not apply to **any** heptagon. So this rule is useful as a way of knowing "at 7 or more boundary points there **might** be such points, but at 6 or below there definitely aren't"